# jQuery Ajax Request is Giving Error on Mobile in Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery 1.11.1 with Asp.net MVC
I am requesting a $.ajax request to my MVC Controller Action and it is working fine on desktop but giving error on mobile version

My jQuery Ajax request is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       url: ajaxurl + 'GetListingByAjax',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       data: JSON.stringify({
           pagenumber: pageno,
           currenturl: location.href
       }),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
           if (data.length > 0) {
              $('#LoadMoreListings').show();
              var FullHTML = GetListingHTML(data);
              $('#loading').remove();               
              pageno++;
           }
           else {
              $('#LoadMoreListings').hide();
              $('#loading').text('No more listings to display');
           }
       },
       error: function (a,b,c) {
            alert('Exeception Description : '+c);
       }
   });
```

And My Controller Action is

```
public JsonResult GetListingByAjax(int pagenumber, string currenturl = "")
{
    var ListingItemsList = new Listing().GetListingAjax(currenturl, pagenumber, 20, 0);
    return Json(ListingItemsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is working fine on desktop and when I run it on mobile it gives me Internal Server Error then I checked the response in Chrome Emulator then it shows following error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pagenumber' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetListingAjax(Int32, System.String)

Then I tried by changing method GET to POST but the error on mobile was same and on desktop it was fine

Can anyone help me please am I doing something in wrong way or i need to add anything extra in this code to be run on mobile

Please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the `pageno` come from?

Comment: It's a variable declared on top of the script

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `pagenumber` parameter in your ajax URL:

```
url: ajaxurl + 'GetListingByAjax',
```

should be something like

```
url: ajaxurl + 'GetListingByAjax/2',
```

In that way the controller gets to make use of the parameter `pagenumber` you've told it to require.

Comment: The data parameter must work for this 
and it will work like GetListingByAjax?pagenumber=2
but my problem is it's working absolutely fine on desktop then what's the problem with mobile